# Get Locked Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-screen

Is there a method to detect if the Auto-Rotation Lock of the device is on or off? My app needs to access that method to lock the orientation during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your Manifest file in your activity for the fixed orientation you want for your Activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

like

```
<activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

or in java code you can use

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to access it through java code? I want it to be modifiable through a toggle button

Comment: yes use setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: I tried locking my device's orientation through settings and tried logging the value for the requested orientation, but the value returns -1 regardless whether I toggle the lock or not.

Answer (score -3):

In iPhone there is a method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

To unlock orientation. if u want to make it lock then change its value (YES to NO) where u want to lock orientation